# Visual Studio Commercial Libraries

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I just upgraded to Visual Studio 2012. I need to be able to use different commercial components for different projects. For instance, one client might need me to use UI components from Developer Express. Another might want me to use Telerik components.

Truth is, I rarely would need to load all of them. I'd really like the ability to load just the sets of components I want without having to bear the time it takes to load all of them each time I start Visual Studio.

I was wondering if there's anyway I can create customized loading scenarios. For example, start VS with component packages a, b, and c or perhaps start it with a, b, d, and e?

Thanks for any pointers.

-- Robert

Comment: if you mean extensions, there are a lot of guides you can use, but tl;dr: "no start-up profile mechanism, use an ssd for performance". Links here: [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996242/can-i-selectively-disable-packages-from-loading-into-vs2010) & [second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995253/vs2010-loads-slowly-can-i-profile-extensions-respective-startup-time)