# Visual Studio 'ResourceManagerPackage' did not load correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, resourcemanager

I was supposed to help a friend for school project about ASP.NET and i installed MS Visual Studio 2015 Community from dreamspark(which i deleted several months ago). But when i tried to open VS2015 this error showed up
[error dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwCAc.png)

when i click yes or no VS opens but when i try to open a website or a project or another thing, this error shows up

[error dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjBrX.png)

Here is the last part(i was going to put full but i'm limited with 5000 chars or something like that) of activity log

```
    
        635
        2016/11/30 08:59:56.797
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
      
      
        636
        2016/11/30 08:59:56.797
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
        {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}
      
      
        637
        2016/11/30 08:59:56.798
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
      
      
        638
        2016/11/30 08:59:56.798
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
        {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}
      
      
        639
        2016/11/30 08:59:56.798
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
      
      
        640
        2016/11/30 08:59:56.798
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
        {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}
      
      
        641
        2016/11/30 08:59:57.272
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage
        {198E76C1-34C0-424D-9957-B3EBD80265FB}
      
      
        642
        2016/11/30 08:59:57.272
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Begin package load [Microsoft Visual Studio Server Explorer Package]
        {198E76C1-34C0-424D-9957-B3EBD80265FB}
      
      
        643
        2016/11/30 08:59:57.391
        Information
        VisualStudio
        End package load [Microsoft Visual Studio Server Explorer Package]
        {198E76C1-34C0-424D-9957-B3EBD80265FB}
      
      
        644
        2016/11/30 09:00:00.641
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage
        {A8F602E2-40CE-4DAF-AE82-A457A91728B9}
      
      
        645
        2016/11/30 09:00:00.641
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Begin package load [Visual Studio Data Designer Extensibility Package]
        {A8F602E2-40CE-4DAF-AE82-A457A91728B9}
      
      
        646
        2016/11/30 09:00:01.411
        Information
        VisualStudio
        End package load [Visual Studio Data Designer Extensibility Package]
        {A8F602E2-40CE-4DAF-AE82-A457A91728B9}
      
      
        647
        2016/11/30 09:00:01.715
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
      
      
        648
        2016/11/30 09:00:01.715
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
        {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}
      
      
        649
        2016/11/30 09:00:01.715
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
      
      
        650
        2016/11/30 09:00:01.715
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
        {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}
      
      
        651
        2016/11/30 09:00:01.715
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
      
      
        652
        2016/11/30 09:00:01.715
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
        {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}
      
      
        653
        2016/11/30 09:00:01.745
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage
        {E1AA7737-69BE-43D0-A425-E3097651E192}
      
      
        654
        2016/11/30 09:00:01.745
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Begin package load [Visual Studio Data Package]
        {E1AA7737-69BE-43D0-A425-E3097651E192}
      
      
        655
        2016/11/30 09:00:03.203
        Information
        VisualStudio
        End package load [Visual Studio Data Package]
        {E1AA7737-69BE-43D0-A425-E3097651E192}
      
      
        656
        2016/11/30 09:00:09.640
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
      
      
        657
        2016/11/30 09:00:09.640
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
        {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}
      
      
        658
        2016/11/30 09:00:09.640
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
      
      
        659
        2016/11/30 09:00:09.640
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
        {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}
      
      
        660
        2016/11/30 09:00:12.807
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
      
      
        661
        2016/11/30 09:00:12.807
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
        {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}
      
      
        662
        2016/11/30 09:00:12.807
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
      
      
        663
        2016/11/30 09:00:12.807
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
        {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}
      
      
        664
        2016/11/30 09:00:14.052
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
      
      
        665
        2016/11/30 09:00:14.052
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
        {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}
      
      
        666
        2016/11/30 09:00:14.052
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
      
      
        667
        2016/11/30 09:00:14.052
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib
        {80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}
      
      
        668
        2016/11/30 09:00:32.776
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage
        {13C3BBB4-F18F-4111-9F54-A0FB010D9194}
      
      
        669
        2016/11/30 09:00:32.777
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Begin package load [CSharpPackage]
        {13C3BBB4-F18F-4111-9F54-A0FB010D9194}
      
      
        670
        2016/11/30 09:00:33.119
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage
        {6CF2E545-6109-4730-8883-CF43D7AEC3E1}
      
      
        671
        2016/11/30 09:00:33.119
        Information
        VisualStudio
        Begin package load [RoslynPackage]
        {6CF2E545-6109-4730-8883-CF43D7AEC3E1}
      
      
        672
        2016/11/30 09:00:34.757
        Error
        VisualStudio
        SetSite failed for package [RoslynPackage]
        {6CF2E545-6109-4730-8883-CF43D7AEC3E1}
        80131500
        An exception was thrown while initializing part "Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.Diagnostics.VisualStudioWorkspaceDiagnosticAnalyzerProviderService".
      
      
        673
        2016/11/30 09:00:34.791
        Error
        VisualStudio
        End package load [RoslynPackage]
        {6CF2E545-6109-4730-8883-CF43D7AEC3E1}
        80131500
        An exception was thrown while initializing part "Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.Diagnostics.VisualStudioWorkspaceDiagnosticAnalyzerProviderService".
```

Comment: Please check [AntonyW's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3995340/5588347). Hope it may help.

Comment: thanks this solved the ResourceManagerPackage error but VS is still closing itself when i try to create project

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ddcaf5dc-9b20-459f-9dd8-c7f5bde3ccca/visual-studio-2015-installs-but-crashes-as-it-starts-to-execute?forum=vssetup)? Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720193/visual-studio-professional-2013-crashes-when-opening-solutions-files) and [Visual Studio crashes when creating a new project](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/613758/visual-studio-crashes-when-creating-a-new-project)